# The entire column does not show when adding an option on the fieldset, jtable and java servlet

Tags: jquery, servlets, jquery-jtable

I am new using jQuery jTable.

I would like to add a dropbox in one of my jTable fieldset. Before I added the dropbox the fieldset content was showing properly. But when I add a function that retrieve the dropbox list from the database through my servlet the entire column is no longer showing. below is a print screen of my table before and after adding the option parameter in my fieldset. I am also posting a part of my `.js` and my servlet. The dropbox I added is working properly though!

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    try {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        /** Code removed purposefully */
        // Convert array list to string 
        String myoptionList = gson.toJson(typeOfProfile);

        // Return in the format required by jTable plugin
        data.put("Result", "OK");
        data.put("Options",myoptionList );

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(data));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        data.put("Result", "ERROR");
        data.put("Message", ex.getMessage());
        String error = gson.toJson(data);
        response.getWriter().print(error);
    }
 //}//end of if statement --if req--
}
```

and here is my java scripte code (jquery)

```
labelProfile   : {
    title : 'Type Profile',
    width : '10%',
    edit : true,
    options: function () {
        var options = [];
        var toSearch = "salut!" //this is just for testing dont mind this

        if (cachedValue) { //Check for cache
            return cachedValue;
        }

        $.ajax({ //If the cache is empty execute the following
            type: "POST",
            url: 'showProfileOptions',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{toSearch:toSearch},
            async: false,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.Result != 'OK'){
                    alert(data.Message)
                    return;
                }
                options = jQuery.parseJSON(data.Options);
            }
        });

    return cachedValue = options;
}//end function
```

And finally a print screen of the table before and after adding the option inside the field set.

- [before editing dropbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfHcE.png)
- [after adding option (dropbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1YBQ.png)

I tried adding a condition such as if `(data.source == 'list')` do not put the dropbox.

Any advice?

Comment: Restructure your code properly, your `{}` for `if-else` do not match.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.
The values in the option list should include The current value (The one load before option is selected) otherwise jTable will not display anything.